# Transfer using psql command from postgres everything related to a database ownership and related entities using bash

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a database that is owned by role `postgres`.

Using the `psql` command in bash I want to transfer the ownership of a database and all everything in it (schema, tables, views, sequences, triggers etc) to the new role.

I have:

```
sudo -u postgres psql << EOF
                ALTER DATABASE ${database} OWNER TO ${role};
                GRANT ALL ON DATABASE ${database} TO ${role};
EOF
```

Is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't do the trick.

It would be nice if you could use `REASSIGN OWNED`, but you cant't do that with the installation superuser, because the system objects cannot change ownership.

You'll have to identify all objects whose ownership you want to change and use `ALTER ... OWNER TO ...` for each one.

Comment: And probably the best starting point for the manual editing would be the output from `pg_dump --schema-only` ...

Comment: even if user is not postgres reassign owned, doesn't reassign all databases, and not a specific one ?

Comment: `REASSIGN OWNED` only affects objects in your current database.